# Elegir usar solo unas clases en bootstrap

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

Quiero utilizar Bootstrap en mi sitio web, pero lo ralentiza muchísimo y solo quiero usar unas cuantas clases (`container`, `d-none`, `d-md-none` y `d-md-block`).

El uso que le quiero dar es el siguiente:

```
<div class="container d-md-none"><p style="text-align: center;"><amp-ad
   layout="fixed"
   width=336
   height=280
   type="adsense"
   data-ad-client="ca-pub-3312952235948569"
   data-ad-slot="3469499644">
</amp-ad></p></div>
<div class="container d-none d-md-block"><p style="text-align: center;"><ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-33312952235948569"
     data-ad-slot="3469499644"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script></p></div>
```

Comment: Puedes buscar todo lo relacionado a esas clases y pasártelo a local, pero no creo que sea rápido o sencillo

Comment: saludos, te sugiero revisar todas tus librerias css, js que uses de manera local mas no apuntando a una URL externa, generalmente esto tambien suele causar la demora o lentitud en la web por usar links externos de css/js etc. Adicional seria bueno que pusieras la estructura de como tienes conformada tu pagina web es decir el codigo completo para analizarlo y dar con tu problema..!!

Comment: Además de tener los archivos `css` y `js` de Bootstrap en tu entorno local, podrías usar las versiones `minified` de los mismos, eso te ahorra algunos bytes. Saludos

Comment: Lamentablemente, BS4 no tiene la [personalización](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/) de la v3. Yo por lo general, cuando quiero usar solo algunas clases, las copio y pego en mi CSS tomando como referencia [la versión en CDN](https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css), puedes usar `Cntrl + F` para moverte con facilidad. Y por último como te recomienda Mauricio, minifica tu código, yo uso [esta herramienta](https://www.minifier.org/) en línea.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar algún servicio web o alguna extensión de navegador que extraiga el CSS usado en un HTML. Te dejo este servicio web como ejemplo: https://uncss-online.com/

Probando tu HTML con el CSS de Bootstrap 4.3.1 obtiene esto:(https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css)

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v4.3.1 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2019 The Bootstrap Authors
 * Copyright 2011-2019 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */:root{--blue:#007bff;--indigo:#6610f2;--purple:#6f42c1;--pink:#e83e8c;--red:#dc3545;--orange:#fd7e14;--yellow:#ffc107;--green:#28a745;--teal:#20c997;--cyan:#17a2b8;--white:#fff;--gray:#6c757d;--gray-dark:#343a40;--primary:#007bff;--secondary:#6c757d;--success:#28a745;--info:#17a2b8;--warning:#ffc107;--danger:#dc3545;--light:#f8f9fa;--dark:#343a40;--breakpoint-xs:0;--breakpoint-sm:576px;--breakpoint-md:768px;--breakpoint-lg:992px;--breakpoint-xl:1200px;--font-family-sans-serif:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";--font-family-monospace:SFMono-Regular,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Liberation Mono","Courier New",monospace}*,::after,::before{box-sizing:border-box}html{font-family:sans-serif;line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent}body{margin:0;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";font-size:1rem;font-weight:400;line-height:1.5;color:#212529;text-align:left;background-color:#fff}p{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:1rem}[type=button]:not(:disabled),[type=reset]:not(:disabled),[type=submit]:not(:disabled),button:not(:disabled){cursor:pointer}::-webkit-file-upload-button{font:inherit;-webkit-appearance:button}.container{width:100%;padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto}@media (min-width:576px){.container{max-width:540px}}@media (min-width:768px){.container{max-width:720px}}@media (min-width:992px){.container{max-width:960px}}@media (min-width:1200px){.container{max-width:1140px}}.custom-control-input.is-valid:focus:not(:checked)~.custom-control-label::before,.was-validated .custom-control-input:valid:focus:not(:checked)~.custom-control-label::before{border-color:#28a745}.custom-control-input.is-invalid:focus:not(:checked)~.custom-control-label::before,.was-validated .custom-control-input:invalid:focus:not(:checked)~.custom-control-label::before{border-color:#dc3545}.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#fff;background-color:#0062cc;border-color:#005cbf}.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(38,143,255,.5)}.btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#fff;background-color:#545b62;border-color:#4e555b}.btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(130,138,145,.5)}.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#fff;background-color:#1e7e34;border-color:#1c7430}.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(72,180,97,.5)}.btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#fff;background-color:#117a8b;border-color:#10707f}.btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(58,176,195,.5)}.btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#212529;background-color:#d39e00;border-color:#c69500}.btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(222,170,12,.5)}.btn-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#fff;background-color:#bd2130;border-color:#b21f2d}.btn-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(225,83,97,.5)}.btn-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#212529;background-color:#dae0e5;border-color:#d3d9df}.btn-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(216,217,219,.5)}.btn-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#fff;background-color:#1d2124;border-color:#171a1d}.btn-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(82,88,93,.5)}.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#fff;background-color:#007bff;border-color:#007bff}.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-outline-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(0,123,255,.5)}.btn-outline-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-outline-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#fff;background-color:#6c757d;border-color:#6c757d}.btn-outline-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-outline-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(108,117,125,.5)}.btn-outline-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-outline-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#fff;background-color:#28a745;border-color:#28a745}.btn-outline-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-outline-success:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(40,167,69,.5)}.btn-outline-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-outline-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#fff;background-color:#17a2b8;border-color:#17a2b8}.btn-outline-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-outline-info:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(23,162,184,.5)}.btn-outline-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-outline-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#212529;background-color:#ffc107;border-color:#ffc107}.btn-outline-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-outline-warning:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(255,193,7,.5)}.btn-outline-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-outline-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#fff;background-color:#dc3545;border-color:#dc3545}.btn-outline-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-outline-danger:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(220,53,69,.5)}.btn-outline-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-outline-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#212529;background-color:#f8f9fa;border-color:#f8f9fa}.btn-outline-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-outline-light:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(248,249,250,.5)}.btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,.btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active{color:#fff;background-color:#343a40;border-color:#343a40}.btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-outline-dark:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus{box-shadow:0 0 0 .2rem rgba(52,58,64,.5)}.custom-control-input:focus:not(:checked)~.custom-control-label::before{border-color:#80bdff}.custom-control-input:not(:disabled):active~.custom-control-label::before{color:#fff;background-color:#b3d7ff;border-color:#b3d7ff}.close:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):focus,.close:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):hover{opacity:.75}.d-none{display:none!important}@media (min-width:768px){.d-md-none{display:none!important}.d-md-block{display:block!important}}@supports ((position:-webkit-sticky) or (position:sticky)){}@media print{*,::after,::before{text-shadow:none!important;box-shadow:none!important}p{orphans:3;widows:3}@page{size:a3}body{min-width:992px!important}.container{min-width:992px!important}}
/*# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.min.css.map */
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que entres a este [enlace](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.css) es la librería entera de `bootstrap 4.6.0` pero sin minificarlo, entras ahí y utilizas `Ctrl + F` e insertas las clases que queres sacar y con eso vas sacando solo lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap tiene una herramienta que te permite descargar solo lo que necesitas:

- Versión 3: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/
- Versión 4: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#sass-options
- Versión 5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/overview/

Answer (score 0):

Existe una extensión para chrome que permite extraer los css usados en las páginas web.
Se llama  [CSS Used](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-used/cdopjfddjlonogibjahpnmjpoangjfff).
Analiza la página y permite extraer solo las reglas usadas. Funciona dentro de la "herramienta para desarrolladores" (F12 o Ctrl+May+I).
Puede ser útil.
Lo mismo ya lo estás haciento pero cargar bootstrap.min.css desde un CDN puede ser algo más rápido que hacerlo desde una copía en tu servidor. Los CDN ponen los recursos más cerca de los usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes descargar Bootstrap y y usar los archivos que NO tengan .min
Si son pocas clases las que utilizas solo extraelas del archivo y si son muchas, te recomiendo usar el mismo archiovo y solo borrar las que no uses.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v5.0.2/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist.zip

Comment: Esta url como se configura? revisar [answer].